# Stack level too deep and before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, infinite-loop

Okay, this thing is driving me crazy. I've got a small method that looks roughly like this:

```
class PdfResult < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :press_ready_url, :low_resolution_url, :error_code,
                  :document_id

  before_save :update_values

  def created?
    return true if press_ready_url.present? && low_resolution_url.present?
  end

  def error?
    error_code == 201 || error_code == 204 ? false : true
  end

  private

  def update_values
    return if error?
    self.updated_at = Time.now
    if created?
      self.error_code = 201
    else
      update_attributes(press_ready_url: nil, low_resolution_url: nil)
      self.error_code = 204
    end
    save!
  end
end
```

And my `error` method just causes `stack level too deep` errors. Can someone help me understand why? By my logic it should work just fine. Thanks. Do I need to guard against `error_code` changing somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`update_attributes` saves the model, triggering callbacks. You shouldn't be triggering a `save` in a `before_save` callback, or yes, you'll exhaust the stack.

Instead of this:

```
update_attributes(press_ready_url: nil, low_resolution_url: nil)
```

Use this:

```
self.press_ready_url = self.low_resolution_url = nil
```

Comment: Wow. Simple and immediate. Thanks so much.